# Can I re-apply considering my previous behavior during the interview process?

Tags: job-change, applications, unprofessional-behavior

So this happened in February 2018, I missed a call from an employer in the morning. Later, I found out that the call was from my dream company to work in. So, I called the back after a few hours but unsuccessful. I called a few times during that day but still unsuccessful.

It was not like no one was answering the call, I was getting a busy tone all the time. I was really disappointed on missing out the opportunity.

After a few days, I got a call again and I answered. The interview was scheduled and I was having conversation with the HR over emails. I cleared the first round and also gave the second round of interview.

As soon as the second round of interview was conducted, I emailed the HR with the update and also asked her to let me know the result. Till 1 week I didn't receive an update about my email and I was curious (to some extent desperate also) to know if I cleared the interview.

A few days (almost after 10 days), I called the HR but again busy tone. I called several times during the day but same. The next day, I called the reception and asked for the HR. The receptionist said that the HR is on leave today. I called the HR again after a week but same busy tone. Again the next day, I called the receptionist few times and he said the HR is not available.

And exactly 2 mins after my last call in the evening, I got an email from HR saying that I have not been selected.

Now I understood that my behavior was very unprofessional no matter how much eager, excited and desperate I was to join this company.

My question is its been more than 6 months now and I am planning to re-apply in the same company again. Can I re-apply considering my previous behavior? And can my behavior in the past affect my future candidature?

Comment: Don't think too much, just reapply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You read too much into your behavior.

In your mind, the phone calls and your failed application are connected and you feel like the company decided to employ someone else *because* you called them so often. For the company, you are just one applicant among many. It's highly probable that your phone calls weren't even connected to your application and they actually had an applicant more suited for the job.

Just apply again and try to be a little bit more patient with HR this time.

Comment: You never know; sometimes repeatedly calling can help.  I got a job once because I interviewed, and then I called to politely inquire once a week until finally one of the secretaries said, "Hey, this guy calls every week.  Are we going to hire him or what?"  Keep in mind also that if you're getting a busy tone, then they don't know that you've called that time.  Busy signals don't "count" in terms of how many calls you've made.

Answer (score 1):

You can always reapply (unless they specifically told you not to). After all, an application is just an offer, which they may or may not take for various reasons. Reasons may be different next time.

If you reapply, you have to decide if you want to address this in your cover letter. Depending how big the Company is and how close the current opening matches the last one.

If you think they remember you, it is perhaps a good idea to explain why you reapplied. Really wanting to work for your "dream company" is a good reason. Other good reasons are: Your skill set has improved since, to make you a better fit - or the new opening does fit you even better.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere: IT can be. All other things being equal, do you want the employee who just needs **any** job, or the one who specifically identifies with your company?

Comment: I ***absolutely*** would not mention this in a covering letter. It has very little potential upside and probably more potential downside.